# Insert link is not working in Markdown Editor on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, edits, markdown

I was editing [one of my old questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59389730/redirect-to-specific-scene-when-app-is-opened-from-fcm-notification-in-ios) and I wanted to add a link for reference, but I saw even if I was adding all the Markdown content correctly, the editor was not converting them to the traditional form that we get/put into a question, answer, or comment. It may be because I'm doing something wrong I'm adding my screenshots bellow:

**My Editor Screenshot:**

[image: Editor screenshot]

**Result of the editor**

[image: Result of the Editor]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You just needed a linebreak after the "Update" heading. I just edited it for you. Whether or not this is a bug, I'm not sure. That can still be discussed here.

Comment: @41686d6564 It works now. I think that it is not a bug, but from my side I was doing everything as it should not perfectly line by line. And I'm not sure weather to consider this as a bug or not.

Comment: Markdown is... *unexpectedly picky* when it comes to certain formatting syntaxes. When in doubt, add an empty line between formatting constructs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mixing HTML and Markdown.

> ```
> <h2>Update:</h2>
> After searching for this question I was able to find
> a solution on my Unity Forum thread that I
> [posted](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-redirect-user-when-app-is-opened-from-notification.798816/).
> But that answer is Obsolete according to the Unity documentation. So
> I'm back to where I started. Thanks in advance.
> ```

A header in Markdown is indicated with a # for h1 and ## for an h2. The ## needs to be followed by a mandatory space since [the move to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark). If I replace the H2 with that Markdown content, your link starts working as well as you can see here.

### Update:

After searching for this question I was able to find a solution on my Unity Forum thread that [I posted](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-redirect-user-when-app-is-opened-from-notification.798816/). But that answer is *obsolete* according to the Unity documentation. So I'm back to where I started. Thanks in advance.

And this is what the Markdown looks like:

> ```
> ## Update:
> After searching for this question I was able to find a solution on my Unity Forum thread that I
> [posted](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-redirect-user-when-app-is-opened-from-notification.798816/).
> But that answer is Obsolete according to the Unity documentation. So
> I'm back to where I started. Thanks in advance.
> ```

Alternatively, add an extra blank line between your header and the paragraph. Blank lines help the markdown parser to reset to a start state and attempt to parse again.

Do know that things like *Update* and *Thanks in advance* [are considered unnecessary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). The revisions of a post can be found in the edit history and we by default accept that you are thankful. Please don't add them to a post and if you find them, edit it out. That text is not needed to understand the post.